# What is the HTTP status code to return when input data is missing?

Tags: http-status-codes

I have written a REST API in `nodejs`.

I want to send HTTP status codes on various events.

For example when data is returned I send HTTP code 200.

What is the status code to return when the input data is missing?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't specific to `nodejs`. HTTP status codes are general -- you can read about them on wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

I think you want client error code `400`, which means `Bad Request`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should return 404, not found. As mentioned in previous answer, HTTP status codes are general.

A tip: try getting grip on HTTP before starting off web development.